# How to merge two unsorted array into a sorted one in the most efficient way?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Suppose we have two arrays:

```
A[] = {7, 15, 2};     //*Size: n* 

B[] = {5, 96, 15};    //*Size: m*
```

and we want to get `c[] = {2, 5, 7, 15, 15, 96}`.

I have got a naive method: 1st sort both arrays **A** and **B** and then merge them to get **c**.

**Time Complexity** : O (nlogn + mlogm + (n + m))

**Space Complexity** : O ( (n + m) )

But is there an efficient way to do it??

Comment: Feast your eyes on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Comment: Since A and B are not sorted, this has the same complexity as sorting an array consisting of their concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No,** it cannot be done better, since this will imply sorting faster than `O(nlogn)` for general case sorting. (In terms of asymptotical time complexity)

First, note that here, `O(nlogn + mlogm) = O((n+m)log(n+m)`

Without loss of generality, `n <= m` (otherwise just switch the arrays).

```
nlogn + mlogm <= (n+m)log(n+m) + (n+m)log(n+m) = 2(n+m)log(n+m)
which is in O((n+m)log(n+m))
(n+m)log(n+m) <= 2n*log(2n) <= 2n*log(2n) + 2m*log(2m) <= 2(nlog(n) +mlog(m) + nlog(2) + mlog(2))
which is in O(nlogn + mlogm)
```

This means, suggested approach, in terms of asymptotical time complexity, is no better than combining the arrays and sorting after this is done.

Now, assume this could have been done in `O(f(n,m))` where `f(n)` is in `o((n+m)log(n+m))` (little o notation here). This means, for any given array - you could split it to two arrays, and run the suggested algorithms. This would have been a contradiction to the fact sorting is `Omega(nlogn)` problem.

Comment: Thanks @amit for such an insight